# How to secure API used by third-parties?

Tags: csrf, api, rest, cors

What I am building is service that can be consumed by third-party. Something like Omdb API for example.

For my service to be functional I needed to disable CSRF on some endpoints.

How can I secure them? To make CORS rules? To whitelist domains or?

Thanks.

Edit:
API trusts a few known host, and handles anti CSRF token via framework. 
Those third-parties will consume our API, but they have to be authorized.

Comment: Unfortunately the requirement is very unspecific. It is not clear what you mean with __some__ endpoint, i.e. where CSRF should be allowed and where not. It is also not clear what you mean with __endpoint__, i.e. browser vs. mobile app etc. I recommend that you describe your setup and environment in more detail and also what the specific risk is you are trying to address (CSRF is not a risk itself, it is a technique).

Comment: If your authorization mechanism uses a bearer or auth token (basically any kind of auth other than cookies) then you're probably covered for CSRF protection.